# UIScrollView paging with buttons

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, paging

i was wondering how you create a paging UIScrollView with buttons as the objects?

So far i have figured out to make a similar UIScrollView with images instead which looks like this:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSArray *pictures = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"nr1"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"nr2"], nil];


    for (int i = 0; i < pictures.count; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

        UIImageView *subview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        subview.image = [pictures objectAtIndex:i];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * pictures.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

}
```

Any tutorials would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You will just add buttons instead of images

Replace this

```
UIImageView *subview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
subview.image = [pictures objectAtIndex:i];
[self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
```

With

```
UIButton *subview = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
subview.frame = frame;
[subview setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helps. But how do i create multiple buttons using this method and how to i link the buttons to an IBAction?

Comment: You can create a dictionary or an array of buttons. Try also setting tags to your buttons so that you can distinguish their each button's respective actions.